# Unable to open sqlite DB file from js axios.get request

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, sqlite, axios

Unable to open sqlite DB file from js axios.get request:[(console.log outputs exception message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAmkx.png). The request may call my PHP controller to select data from DB and return it json-encoded.

An another side, PHP contoller makes it's job good: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LythK.png)

In this way i trying send an axios request from Vue form: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP14e.png)
or code:

```
Vue.createApp({
    data: () => ({
        processors:'',
        memory:'',
        drives:'',
        motherboards:'',
        cases:'',
    }),
    methods:{
        fetchProcessors:function (){
            axios.get('/src/controllers/getProcessors.php').then(
                (response) => {
                    this.processors = response.data;
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
    },
    created:function (){
        console.log('vue is ok');
        this.fetchProcessors();
    }
}).mount(".js-form");
```

PHP controller code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Doctrine\DBAL;

$connectionParams = [
    'url' => 'sqlite3:///db/calc_db.sqlite3'
];


try {
    $conn = DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);
    $data = $conn->fetchAllAssociative('SELECT name, cost FROM processors');
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've tryed to:

- give chmod 777 to whole project
- make request with phpstorm tools (returns same exception message)
- send const json from controller - it wotks good, proofs that js request and php controller working together normaly, trouble is in connection to DB file (i think so)
- use sqlite driver instead of sqlite3

---

[full stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF1IE.png)

Comment: There are no credentials in your connection url?

Comment: @geertjanknapen, i think, sqlite dont require this. Anyway, I've tryed url such as sqlite3://ignored:ignored@localhost:8000/db/calc_db.sqlite3 with the same result

Comment: You seem to be correct, however, can you try `sqlite:///db/calc_db.sqlite3` and `sqlite:///db/calc_db.sqlite`, since the docs only mention you need `sqlite:` for a sqlite database, ommiting the `3`

Comment: @geertjanknapen, this makes no effect (i mean: php works; js->call php throws exception) :(
Anyway, if php script can reach DB file with tnis param, this srcript requested from js should make it in the same way, isn't it?

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as logs, error messages or stack traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in 'path' param: i've launched my script from project root (working directory), so relative path to my DB builds correctly.

On web-server WD was a path, that i gave in request (controllers dir), so relative path to my DB builds incorrectly.

I've replaced path param like this and everything is OK:

```
$connectionParams = [
    'path' => dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '/db/calc_db.sqlite3',
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite'
];
```